# Can we create a custom wrapper for mock annotation of jmockit?

Tags: java, junit, annotations, mocking, jmockit

Can we create a custom wrapper for mock annotation or MockUp class of jmockit ? If its possible can you explain how can we done it.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a free "we turn your vision into code" service, you know.

Comment: I wanted to create a custom annotation or wrapper that refers to the mockit annotation of jmokit.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "custom wrapper" for JMockit's `@Tested` annotation (ie, use it as a meta-annotation), but not for any of the other annotations, `@Mock` included. So, the answer is no, it's not possible.